# Jquery Isotope Library move select to first position?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using jquery isotope on my site and I have a page where I has some links that when one is clicked it reoders the isotope items so the clicked link's associated div gets reorded to the first position. I can find any examples of this so i'm helping someone could lend a hand with this.

Thanks
C

EDIT:

Here is what I have so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfwnL/2/)

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  var sortName = $('#container .active');
  $('#container').isotope({ sortBy : sortName });
});
```

I've commented the JS pane with what i'm trying to do. This is not even close I don't think but I am trying. I think i'm going the wrong way about it. Maybe I should be using data-something="" instead.

Please let me know if you have any better ideas.

Also, I need to have them stay in their original positions (apart from the selected one obviously). so if `6` was selected it would be `6123457` or if `3` was selected it would be `3124567`. The previous item selected would move back into it's original position.

Comment: please post your markup, css, and javascript. Preferably a JSFiddle also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forked your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJABf/). Check it out and see if it matches your expectations. Basically what I did was drop the notion of sorting those items, because if I read your intention right, you only needed to put one `div` in front of the other. I wasn't sure what's to happen with the other items when you do this rearrangement, so I left them in their last position.

Edit:
I guess I misread the question or had not enough coffee that day. I've updated the fiddle to better match what you [described](http://jsfiddle.net/QJABf/3/).

Comment: Thanks @guessimtoolate - That is spot on for the sorting, thankyou. Sorry I wasnt clear about the other items but I actualy need to have them stay in their original positions (apart from the selected one obviously). so if `6` was selected it would be `6123457` or if `3` was selected it would be `3124567` is that possible? Thanks again, C

Comment: I went back to your original idea and implemented sorting as it was easier that cut-and-paste approach that I thought would do. I mean it should be doable with some array operations, but sorting did prove to be easier to do. I added an updated fiddle that matches your description.